# Problem loading content into DIV w/ jQuery

Tags: jquery, iframe, jqtransform

I have a div that I am trying to make hidden by default, and then shown with a button click.  My code works fine as long as the div is not set to style="display:none;"  As soon as I set this the DIV doesn't load the style sheet correctly.  I think I need some code to initialize the page load when the button is clicked.  Here is the jQuery I am using:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('#overlayHide').live('click', function(event) {        
         jQuery('#overlay').toggle('show');
    });
});
```

Again, this code works fine as long as I allow the div to load when the page loads. As soon as I try set display:none the CSS looks messed up when I load.

Here is my code:

```
<div id="overlay" style="display:none;"><iframe  id="contactIframe"  frameborder="0"  vspace="0"  hspace="0"  marginwidth="0"  marginheight="0" width="500"  height="500" scrolling="np"  height="400"  src="http://foobar.com/contact/demo.php">
</iframe></div>


jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('#overlayHide').click(function(event) {        
         jQuery('#overlay').toggle('slow');
    });
});
```

It works fine as long as I don't set display:hidden, but I need the div to be hidden on page load.

Comment: You probably don't need live in this case... just the regular .click() Live is less performatic.

Comment: You're right, I tried removing live but still the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix this by displaying the iframe in a separate file, and then using AXAJ to load the separate file into a DIV...  Weird.

Answer (score 1):

it's not `show` it's `slow`:

```
jQuery('#overlay').toggle('slow');
```

Please read the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/).

EDIT:
Since there are no much info provided, and the plugin used inside the iframe is [working](http://enblogopedia.com/project/so/toggle_iframe/) just fine, I suggest you using the *[off-left technique](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/API/1.7/Tabs#Why_does...)* something like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('#overlayHide').live('click', function(event) {        
         jQuery('#overlay').toggleClass('hideMe');
         return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: it's working just fine [here](http://enblogopedia.com/project/so/toggle_iframe/), what CSS is messed up exactly? the iframe? also are you setting it to hidden or none?!

Comment: I am setting it to none, it's a few of the styles that the jqtransform plugin uses that aren't lining up.  I'm just confused why it would work fine without display:none, but different with it.

Comment: the styles are INSIDE the iframe? also are you applying the plugin on the iframe content? and the plugin is loaded inside it?

Comment: Correct, the styles are all loaded by the page inside the iFrame.  The plug in is applied to some of the inputs inside the form (which is also inside the iFrame).  Is there a way to force the page to load the content of a display:none div, even if it's not displaying it?  It seems like the toggle loads the div differently and that's where it's getting messed up.

Comment: Still not too much info you provided here, I tried to use the plugin inside the iframe and it's [still working](http://enblogopedia.com/project/so/toggle_iframe/) just fine, one thing that you can use is the [off-left technique](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/API/1.7/Tabs#Why_does...)